# What are the implications of being "cut off from the Force"?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, the-last-jedi

Going back to legends for a moment, there's been several depictions of beings being cut off from the Force. Notably was the [Sever Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sever_Force) ability used throughout legends to cut someone else (or oneself) off from the Force, either temporarily or permanently. There's also the case of [Kyle Katarn](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kyle_Katarn) who did it to himself before the events of [Jedi Outcast](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Jedi_Knight_II:_Jedi_Outcast), though whether this was Sever Force or something else is unknown, and he later gets those powers back.

In The Last Jedi, we see this concept make a reappearance when we discover that:

> Luke Skywalker has cut himself off from the Force.

As [the answer to another question confirms](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177946/did-luke-really-shut-himself-off/177953#177953), this is indeed what has happened. In the Disney Canon, this seems to result in:

- No longer using Force powers actively (push, pull, mind trick, etc)
- No longer sensing the Force passively (aforementioned character was unable to sense things going on around them in the galaxy).
- No longer detectable by other Force awares who might be looking for them.
- Unlike legends, this appears to be a conscious decision, and is able to be reversed at will.

My question then is do we know what it means in the Disney canon to be cut off from the Force? Are they just choosing not to use and ignore the Force, or is there something more to it? Does it involve a severance between the user and Midichlorians, the Midichlorians and the Force itself, the user and the Force itself, or something entirely different?

As stated above, there's plenty on this already in legends canon. Looking for what we know so far in  the Disney canon.

Comment: I think that Luke is the first person to do this in Disney canon. Perhaps the novelization for the film provides some more info on what it means.

Comment: @Thunderforge That's what I'm hoping, in the novelization or some sort of movie/universe guide that's come out since. In particular, if the answer is really that it's a simple "choice" that can be flipped on and off, then this is just begging more questions like why Yoda/Obi-wan/others wouldn't have done the same to hide.

Comment: In Disney canon, we don't know that Obi-Wan didn't. Yoda was monitoring Luke via the Force, so he'd want to keep his connection, plus he was hiding near a Dark Side cave which helped mask his presence.

Comment: @phantom42 I don't think it's been explicitly stated either way (or at least, evidence that he's been using it to prove the contrary), but if true, [then he seems to know alot for someone unconnected to the Force](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AUjiLcb3qE).

Comment: @phantom42 Actually, [during the events of the Journals of Ben Kenobi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi#Exile_on_Tatooine), Obi-wan senses Luke in danger and uses the Force to save him. So we have reason to believe he didn't cut himself off. Admittedly though, this also gives us a reason why (to protect Luke).

Comment: I'm referring more to the time period at the start of ANH. Also, clearly Jedi can re-connect without *too* much trouble, as Luke does in TLJ, so it's entirely possible that he drops out when he needs to feel safer and reconnects when danger has likely passed.

Answer (score 1):

To go through a couple more examples:

**Ulic Qel-Droma**(sic)

This is the best known example. Ulic was a Sith Lord about 4000 BBY. He worked with Exar Kun in the Great Sith War. In the aftermath, he was stipped of the Force. He couldn't use the Force, and retired to the planet Rhen Var.

**Callista**

She was an ex-Jedi, who became Luke's lover. She could technically still use the Force, however, she could only use the dark side.

All examples posed a lack of ability to use the Force to various.degrees. They also could not sense the Force.

Comment: There's also the Jedi Exile of KotOR2. Their experience was extremely traumatic and permanently changed their relationship with the Force, though the player gets to decide how.

Comment: "As stated above, there's plenty on this already in legends canon. Looking for what we know so far in the Disney canon."

Comment: Don't forget Revan; ik it's more a mind wipe than a severance of the force but the user had no idea they were force sensitive

Answer (score 1):

**What Luke did to himself is somewhat different then sever Force in Legends.**

Force supposed to be field of energy that permeates all living beings (and apparently even non-living objects) . Some individuals, when they enter certain state of mind, could "feel" this energy field and its fluctuations, and even use it to manipulate other beings or objects. In Legends, this ability could be severed by creating "wall of light", barrier of light side energy that would not allow targeted individual to connect with larger part of Force in universe. Note that this barrier was not easy to break, even if individual created it around himself ( [Meetra Surik](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Meetra_Surik) ).

From what we know, Luke didn't go that far. He simply decided not to use Force, not to enter the state of mind that was required to feel and manipulate the Force. This could be compared to someone knowing to drive the car, but for some reason never taking the car's keys.

**Why Snoke or Kylo Ren could not detect him ?** Probably for the same reason Jedi Council could not detect Palpatine's Force abilities even when he stood right in front of them - Palpatine was very careful not to connect with the Force, and so was Luke . Note that Force sensitive people, even if they don't know anything about the Force subconsciously use it, like Anakin as a boy on Tatooine or boy with broom in *Last Jedi* .